# Postgres throws this error: invalid input syntax for type date: "". But only one Heroku server but not the other one

Tags: postgresql, heroku

This is very strange so it is hard to explain.

I made two identical(I believe) apps on Heroku.
One is for development and the other one is for production.
The only thing I did about the two Postgres for both environments is installing Postgresql through the resource tab.
So, the source code is the same and the Postgresql is the same.

Only one thing different between them is the NODE_ENV.
NODE_ENV is set to 'development' for the development Heroku environment but 'production' for the production Heroku environment.

But only the production environment throws error messages.

```
e.g.
invalid input syntax for type date: ""
```

But the development environment doesn't.

How NODE_ENV can affect the behaviour of Postgresql?

Anyone has any idea about this?

EDIT: this is not about the Postgresql error but about how NODE_ENV can affects how Postgresql acts.

Comment: Huh, I changed the NODE_ENV value to 'development' so it stopped working differently.
Still why? NODE_ENV affects Postgresql. I wonder.

Comment: I don't think `NODE_ENV` _is_ affecting the behaviour of PostgreSQL. I suspect it's causing your code to provide a valid date string vs. an empty string for some reason. Without more information we can't say much more than that. You'd need to show us your code where you try to run whatever query you're running.

Comment: This `""` is an invalid  date value in Postgres period. I suspect the `NODE_ENV='development'` is redirecting the errors somewhere else while `NODE_ENV='production'` is allowing them to bubble up to the end user.

Comment: Yes, the error message is about the date value. 
The thing is when NODE_ENV is set to 'development', the rule is relaxed.
But if NODE_ENV='production' it throws the error.
Actually, the error message doesn't matter. 
If I set the default date value to null, it will throw other error messages which weren't thrown when NODE_ENV='development'.
In short, Postgres acts differently.
Also, when it throws the error message, (of course it is DB error) it crashes the server.